# Owner & Group getting changed to 0?

Tags: permissions, ftp

Using Cyberduck for FTP and a Linux server.

I'm getting Server 500 error [an error occurred while processing this directive] on my website files (which are all public, set to 755 on folders and 644 on files).

The problem seems to be that the owner and group are being reverted to 0 as soon as I edit or create files. Normally (and before this started happening), the owner and group were 500 and 501.

When I changed owner and group on a file through terminal with chown 500:501 /path/to/file they start working again, I can visit the webpage and when I check the file permissions, owner and group are 500 and 501.

BUT they revert right back to 0 as soon as I make any edit to the file (doesn't matter what) or if I create a new file, and the page becomes unviewable again with the same error.

This never used to happen. I used to be able to edit and create files with Cyberduck without the owner/group being changed, and without errors. I checked my etc/group file and it had the correct group set at the bottom.

Comment: +1 but which program are you using to edit the files, @Maya ?

Comment: What user are you connecting in as when using Cyberduck? It sounds like you are connecting as the root user (UID 0) rather than the user with UID 500.

Comment: I'm using Sublime to edit code. Thank you for the info! That helps. I'll look into that more.

Comment: YES, this seems to have worked. I reconfiged my FTP to the user shown in my etc/group folder (that corrosopnds with the group # on my non messed up files). Now I can edit and add files and they show up properly. Thank you!